# Handling null in JSON RESPONSE

Tags: json, android-json

I am getting json response as

```
["L500","Success",null]
```

How can I handle it

Here is what I tried

```
jsonArray.getJSONArray(2).getJSONObject(2).equals(JSONObject.NULL);
```

However, it produces the error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value null at 2 of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

If null I need to show a Toast message to user something like "No records found".

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? What does it do, and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Getting org.json.JSONException: Value null at 2 of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing

```
jsonArray.getJSONArray(2).getJSONObject(2).equals(JSONObject.NULL);
```

with

```
jsonArray.get(2).equals(null);
```